# Trouble with CSS height: 100% Bottom Icons Pushed Below Bottom of Page

Tags: css, height

I've searched on Google and a bit on here and couldn't find a suitable solution to my problem. I had finished a site design but forgotten to include social media links. To remedy this, I decided to put icons on the bottom of the page. The problem is that the icons will not go to the bottom when content doesn't fill the whole page. I tried the usual solutions found on Google, but the height of the container and the content divs were preventing these solutions from working. I went in an adjusted the heights of html, body, container to 100%.

The problem I now face is when I set the height of the content div to 100%, it stretches past the bottom of the page. I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ML2se/) set up to demonstrate this problem. I have the CSS code below with the mobile and animation bits removed.

```
    html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background:url(../images/jel_fish.png) #0485AA;
    background:url(../images/jel_fish.png), linear-gradient(#7db9e8 0%, #67a3e0 62%, #1e5799 100%);
    background:url(../images/jel_fish.png), -o-linear-gradient(#7db9e8 0%, #67a3e0 62%, #1e5799 100%);
    background:url(../images/jel_fish.png), -ms-linear-gradient(#7db9e8 0%, #67a3e0 62%, #1e5799 100%);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: rude_metal;
    src: url('vtks_rude_metal.ttf'),  url('vtks_rude_metal.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.med {
    border:0;
    float:left;
    margin:12%;
    position:relative;
}
.center {
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.center img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    width:720px;
}
.content {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 75px;
    position:relative;
}
img {
    border:0;
}
p {
    font-size:14pt;
}
ul.dropdown {
    color:#0a4b63;
    display:inline-block;
    font:36px rude_metal;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    padding-left:50px;
    z-index:1;
}
ul.dropdown a {
    color:#0a4b63;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown li a:hover {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 22px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.dropdown ul {
    background:#75B1E5;
    border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
    border:3px solid #0485AA;
    border-top:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:-25px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
.posters {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
.s_media div {
    height:100px;
    top:-100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.s_media img {
    left:20%;
    height:100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
.s_media img + img {
    left:40%;
    position:absolute;
}
.s_media img + img + img {
    left:60%;
    position:absolute;
}
.s_media img + img + img + img {
    left:80%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating CSS for s_media div with

```
.s_media div{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This should make the social media div stick to bottom of the page.

Comment: While it does stick the div toe the bottom of the page, but it covers any content going to the bottom of the page. If I insert an image that stretches to the bottom of the page, the icons in the div will cover the inserted image.

Comment: If the markup is what you specified in jsfiddle then that should not be a problem as content and s_media are two separate divs. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/j9hYG/

Comment: It looks fine in the JSFiddle window, but if you fullscreen it you'll see my problem. The problem is that the empty content div stretches past the height of the screen, forcing the user to unnecessarily scroll down.

EDIT: Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I was able to make your answer work by taking the s_media out of the container and messing with the padding/margin/etc. to achieve the desired look. The height was no longer a problem.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will solve your other problems, but adding overflow: hidden to the body selector will remove the vertical scroll bar:

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background:url(../images/jel_fish.png) #0485AA;
  background:url(../images/jel_fish.png), linear-gradient(#7db9e8 0%, #67a3e0 62%, #1e5799 100%);
  background:url(../images/jel_fish.png), -o-linear-gradient(#7db9e8 0%, #67a3e0 62%, #1e5799 100%);
  background:url(../images/jel_fish.png), -ms-linear-gradient(#7db9e8 0%, #67a3e0 62%, #1e5799 100%);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
}
```

I personally prefer to use [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to simplify layout.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the scroll bar appearing on the side of the page. I will look into Twitter Bootstrap, though.